# How to fill a QPixMap with rectangles with a custom pattern?

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qpixmap

If there is any way to fill a Rectangle with a custom pattern like this (If you can't see it, its a "+" that fills the Rectangle)? look here:
[image: look here]

For now I managed to create rectangles with a QPainter and painter.drawRect (x, y, z, b) and filled them with painter.setBrush (Qt:: Dense1Pattern). But I want to fill it with my custom pattern, so it creates a checked pattern with multiple Rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement a pattern then use a QBrush and set the QPixmap (or QImage) as texture:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPainter>


QPixmap createPattern(const QSize & size, const QColor & background=Qt::white, const QColor & foreground=Qt::black){
    QPixmap pixmap(size);
    pixmap.fill(background);
    {
        QPainter painter(&pixmap);
        painter.setPen(foreground);
        painter.drawLine(0, size.height()/2, size.width(), size.height()/2);
        painter.drawLine(size.width()/2, 0, size.width()/2, size.height());
    }
    return pixmap;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QPixmap pixmap(400, 400);
    {
        QPainter painter(&pixmap);
        QBrush brush;
        brush.setTexture(createPattern(QSize(25, 25), Qt::green, Qt::yellow));
        painter.fillRect(pixmap.rect(), brush);
    }
    QLabel label;
    label.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    label.setPixmap(pixmap);
    label.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```